# Add an ssh key using Chef

Tags: ruby, linux, ssh, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to add a private SSH key to a machine using Chef.

*I'm new to Chef, and not a ruby programmer so the code below might be less-than optimum*

My recipe includes the following:

```rb
execute "add private ssh key" do
  command 'ssh-add ' + ::File.join('/home', node['user'], '.ssh/keys/id_rsa')
  user node['user']
end
```

and upon running `sudo chef-client` on the target machine, then we get "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent" when attempting to add the SSH key.

This indicates the ssh client is not running, so I change the recipe to start with `eval $(ssh-agent) &&` in order to start the client. After this upon running `sudo chef-client`  in the shell we see the command in green, indicating the command was executed successfully.

However, the `id_rsa` key has not been added for the logged in user, and I see the SSH client is not running.

I probably am barking up the wrong tee, but this suggests to me that the key was added for a different user - maybe side affect of Chef being ran with sudo (Chef does not work when sudo is not used).

Has anyone experience with working around this problem, or adding SSH keys to machines using Chef?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure from your question what you are looking for.  The ssh-add should be used to load up the agent on a users host so the private keys can be forwarded through from host to host.  This should be done with a login script such as .bashrc on the users client.

Sorry if I'm mistaking but I think you more than likely want to add a public key to the authorized_keys file for users on servers so they can be authenticated by a private key.  To do this you can append the line in an execute resource:

```
execute "add pub key" do
  command "echo #{node['pub_key']} >> ~#{node['ssh_user']}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  not_if "grep #{node['pub_key']} ~#{node['ssh_user']}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
end
```

A slightly better way would be to use the `line` cookbook which gives you an insert_if_no_match resource.

Probably the best way would be to use the `users` community cookbook which can install public keys from data_bags.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your command statement to this:

```
command "ssh-add /home/#{node['user']} ./ssh/keys/id_rsa"
```

Comment: this appears to be a style change. how will changing how my string is concatenated help?